# Maximum subarray sum with at most K elements

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, deque, prefix-sum

Maximum subarray sum with at most K elements :

Given an array of integers and a positive integer k, find the maximum sum of a subarray of size less than or equal to k. A subarray is a contiguous part of the array.
For example, if the array is `[5, -3, 5, 5, -3, 5]` and k is `3`, then the maximum subarray sum with at most `k` elements is `10`, which is obtained by the subarray `[5, 5]`

My initial thought was to use the Kadane's algorithm with a sliding window of K. Below is the code:

```
maxi = nums[0]
max_so_far = 0
prev = 0
for i in range(len(nums)):
    max_so_far += nums[i]
    if (i - prev) >= k:
        max_so_far -= nums[prev]
        prev += 1
    maxi = max(maxi, max_so_far)
    if max_so_far < 0:
        max_so_far = 0
        prev = i + 1
return maxi
```

but this approach won't work for the test case -

```
nums = [5, -3, 5, 5, -3, 5]
k = 3
```

Edit: I found the solution - Prefix Sum + Monotonic Deque - O(n) Time complexity

```
def maxSubarraySum(self, nums, k) -> int:
    prefix_sum = [0] * len(nums)
    prefix_sum[0] = nums[0]
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        prefix_sum[i] = prefix_sum[i-1] + nums[i]
    q = deque()
    for i in range(k):
        while len(q) > 0 and prefix_sum[i] >= prefix_sum[q[-1]]:
            q.pop()
        q.append(i)
    maxi = max(prefix_sum[:k])
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if q[0] < i:
            q.popleft()
        if i + k - 1 < len(nums):
            while len(q) > 0 and prefix_sum[i + k - 1] >= prefix_sum[q[-1]]:
                q.pop()
            q.append(i + k - 1)
        maxi = max(maxi, prefix_sum[q[0]] - prefix_sum[i-1])
    return maxi
```

Comment: Checkout [Maximum sum of contiguous sub-sequence with length at most k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451778/maximum-sum-of-contiguous-sub-sequence-with-length-at-most-k/55459694#55459694)

Comment: [O(n)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/151327/10147)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an O(n) solution at https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/151327/10147

We can have O(n log n) with divide and conquer. Consider left and right halves of the array: the solution is either in (1) the left half exclusively, (2) the right half exclusively, or (3) a suffix of the left combined with a prefix of the right.

To solve (3) in O(n), iterate from the middle to the left, recording for each index the higher of the highest seen or the total sum. Then iterate to the right and add a similar record for prefix length `l` with the recorded value for index `k - l` (or the longest possible if `k-l` is out of bounds) in the first iteration.

For the example, `[5, -3, 5, 5, -3, 5] k = 3`, we have:

```
[5, -3, 5, 5, -3, 5]
 7   5  5 <---
     --->  5   5  7
     ^-----^
       best = 5 + 5 = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue in your code is it is always taking some of 3 elements after 3rd iteration.

Iterations :

`1` : `sum_so_far = 5` `maxi = 5`

`2` : `sum_so_far = 5+(-3)` `maxi = 5`

`3` : `sum_so_far = 5+(-3)+5` `maxi = 7`

`4` : `sum_so_far = (-3)+5+5` `maxi = 7`

`5` : `sum_so_far = 5+5+(-3)` `maxi = 7`

`6` : `sum_so_far = 5+(-3)+5` `maxi = 7`

It is difficult to achieve expected result in single loop.

Suggestion : you should always try to debug your code, first manually and still facing issue you can take help of [GDB online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) for further debugging.

This is what I wrote as a solution to above statement.

```
ar = [5, -3, 5, -5, -30, 50]
k = 3 
sub_sum = 0
temp_list = []
sum_list = []
for i in range(len(ar)):
    temp,j = 0,0
    while (i+j) < len(ar):
        temp += ar[i+j]
        temp_list.append(ar[i+j])
        j += 1
    if temp > sub_sum :
        sub_sum = temp
        sum_list = temp_list.copy()
    temp_list = []

print (sub_sum)
print (sum_list)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this code won't catch cases where the [k:] values in the list may be largest, for example this code will fail to catch the max sum for lists like: [5, -3, 5, -105, 30, 50] or even [5, -3, 5, -5, -30, 50], where the answer would located at the end of the list, e.g. 80 and 50 respectively.

Comment: Yeah rightly pointed out, by changing `while j < k :`  to `while (i+j) < len(ar)` solves the problem.  And I am not sure if the question mentions to display the sub list, However I have modified code to display the sub list.

Answer (score 1):

Use two indices.

On each iteration:

First, advance the rear index when:

- The sum between the two indices is <= 0
- The distance between the two indices (inclusive) is k
- The forward index is at the end of the array
- The value of the element at the rear index is <= 0

Then, advance the forward index when:

- We didn't advance the rear index
- We advanced the rear index past the forward index

Keep track of the current & best sum between indices. Updates are O(1) since we just need to adjust for the element being included or excluded from the range between our indices.

Stop when the rear index reaches the end of the array.

If you want the matching indices as well, store these every time you find a new best sum.

Ruby code (read as pseudocode if Ruby is unfamiliar)

```
def f(arr, k)
  cur = arr[0]
  best = arr[0]
  best_indices = [0,0]
  i = 0
  j = 0
  
  while j <= arr.length - 1 && i < arr.length - 1
    if cur <= 0 || j-i+1 == k || j == arr.length - 1 || arr[i] <= 0
      cur -= arr[i]
      i += 1
      if j < i
        j += 1
        cur += arr[j]
      end
    else
      j += 1
      cur += arr[j]
    end
    if cur > best
      best = cur
      best_indices = [i, j]
    end
  end
  puts "best = #{best}, range = [#{best_indices[0]}, #{best_indices[1]}]"
end
```

Sample Results

```
> f([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-10000,1,1,1], 5)
best = 5, range = [0, 4]

> f([1,1,1,1,-10000,1,1,1], 5)
best = 4, range = [0, 3]

> f([1,1,1,-10000,1,1,1,1], 5)
best = 4, range = [4, 7]

> f([1,1,26,26,-100,26,26,1,1,1,1], 5)
best = 55, range = [5, 9]

> f([-100, -100, 26,26,-100,26,26,-100,1,1,1], 5)
best = 52, range = [2, 3]

> f([-100, -100, 70,70,-100,70,70,-100,1,1,1], 5)
best = 180, range = [2, 6]
```

Comment: Will this cover cases where very large negatives have positives on both sides?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I think it should work fine in all cases. I added code and some test runs to the end of my answer. If you have a specific test case you'd like to see, comment on it and I'll run it.

Comment: This assumes the answer has to include at least one element. In an all-negative array, it will return the element closest to zero. This is easily handled if the OP wants to return no elements in this case.

Comment: This needs modification to handle a situation like: [17,32,23,-67,69,94] for k=5. Here, the first 3 are sufficient to overcome the 67, but after we advance the rear index past the 17, we need to advance it all the way past the 67 before advancing the forward index because 32+23-67 <= 0. I'll modify when I have time.

Comment: By the way, here's one O(n) solution: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/151327/10147

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I've misinterpreted your question, but as I understand it, you want to find the largest value that can be summed in a range (as small as 1 or as large as 'k') in your array.

I've wrote a quick code that does just that, let me know if it falls short in anyway.

```
arr = [5, -3, 5, 5, -3, 5]
k = 3

max_sum = 0

for e,i in enumerate(arr): #Run through array

    for j in range(k): #Run through range length values 1 - k

        sub_sum_of_range = 0
        value_list = []

        for l in range(j, j+1): #Use range length values to calculate largest sum possible

            if e+l < len(arr): #if array len is 6, don't allow code to calculate arr[6]
                value_list.append(arr[e+l]) #Current list being summed
                sub_sum_of_range = sub_sum_of_range + arr[e+l]

                if sub_sum_of_range > max_sum: #If sum is greater than current max, replace it
                    max_sum = sub_sum_of_range
                    max_value_list = value_list

print(max_sum)
print(max_value_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar solution which is a bit more explicit:

```py
DEBUG = True
  
def log(msg):
    if DEBUG:
        print(msg)

def calc_max_window(nums, k):
    nums_len = len(nums)
    assert k <= nums_len, f"k must be less or equal to {nums_len}"
    max_sum = 0
    max_window = []
    log(f"Array to check: {nums}")
    for window_size in range(1, k + 1):
        log(f"Checking windows of size: {window_size}")
        for i in range(nums_len - window_size + 1):
            window = nums[i:i + window_size]
            log(f"\tChecking window: {window}")
            sum_window = sum(window)
            if sum_window > max_sum:
                log(f"\t\tWindow is new max: {sum_window}")
                max_sum, max_window = sum_window, window
    log(f"max_sum: {max_sum}, max_window: {max_window}")
    return max_window, max_sum


nums = [5, -3, 5, 5, -3, 5]
calc_max_window(nums, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you drop the first element

```
if (i - prev) >= k:
    max_so_far -= nums[prev]
    prev += 1
```

the new range may start with a negative number. This is never good. You might be tempted to drop all negatives as well:

```
if (i - prev) >= k:
    max_so_far -= nums[prev]
    prev += 1
    while prev < i and nums[prev] < 0:
        max_so_far -= nums[prev]
        prev += 1
```

But this is not enough because the new range may still have a prefix sum less than zero, which would require restarting the range at that point.